# How can I construct an sql query for the following result?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables:

1. table1

   ```
       id|val1|val2    
       1 | 100|200    
       2 | 200|400
   ```
2. table2

   ```
   id|val1|val2    
   1 | 100|250    
   3 | 500|400
   ```

table3 should be like,

```
id|val1|val2
1 | 100|250
2 | 200|400
3 | 500|400
```

These 2 tables have some common elements.

I want to write a  query which results in  following condition:

**Table3 = Table2 + ( Table1- Table2)**

The common elements should be deleted from **Table1** and the remaining data should be taken.

Comment: table structure? define "some common elements"?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ..... I tried with union all...but i am unable to achieve the requirment

Comment: can you define which are considered common elements?

Comment: @Takarii...Here my primary key is "id". Id=1 is present in table1 and table2. I want to take the details record from table2, for id=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
select ifnull(id_2, id_1) id, 
       ifnull(val1_2, val1_1) val1, 
       ifnull(val2_2, val2_1) val2 
from (  
       select t1.id id_1, t1.val1 val1_1, t1.val2 val2_1, 
              t2.id id_2, t2.val1 val1_2, t2.val2 val2_2
       from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
       union
       select * from table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
) x
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eee4/15)